# Split string, epeat for number of lines, and insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert, split

I have the following problem:

If the string is:
1 x something`br`1 x something else`br`2 x something even different

I want that to insert into my mysql database as follows:
1 something
1 something else
2 something even different

So we need to separate each line that needs to be inserted when there is a `br`, also split (explode) where there is a " x " for a new column and insert the first part into the 1st column and the 2nd part in the 2nd column.

Thanks!

Comment: Normalise your database unless you know for certain that there will be an absolute limit to the number of columns.

Comment: Otherwise, have you actually tried anything yourself... you mention explode(), have you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..

```
<?php

$string = '1 x something <br> 1 x something else <br> 2 x something even different';

$lines = explode('<br>', $string);

foreach($lines AS $line){

    list($quantity, $item) = explode('x', $line);

    $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO TABLE (field_for_quantity, field_for_item) VALUES (%u, "%s")', $quantity, $item);
    mysql_query($sql);

}

?>
```